# Probability, Finding number of cases

Tags: probability

Suppose $x_1$ , $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$ >0 then $x_1$+$x_2$+$x_3$+$x_4$=18

a)   $x_1$>5

b)   $x_4$ $\neq$ 5

c)   $x_2$=2 and $x_3$=5

d)   $x_1$+$x_2$=5

Please Correct Me

a)   $\binom{4+(18-6)-1}{18-6}$

b)   $\binom{4+(18-6)-1}{18-6}$ - $\binom{4+(18-5-6)-1}{18-5-6}$

c)   $\binom{2+11-1}{11}$

d)   $\binom{2+5-1}{5}$*$\binom{2+13-1}{13}$

Comment: I take it (c) asks for $x_2=2$ **and** $x_3=5$. That leaves $11$ between the other two guys. Since the $x_i$ have to be positive, there are $10$ ways to do it. If we allowed $0$, there would be $12$ ways, which is your answer. So **if** they really want positive, you are using wrong formula. Similar issue in (d) and probably elsewhere.

Comment: In my view such "questions" should not be accepted. In their refusal of producing even a measly representation of the actual problem they show a total disrespect for the community at work here. Giving an answer beginning with "I conjecture  you are asking whether $\ldots$" is subsidizing such an attitude.

Comment: @Hooman: Your question said explicitly $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4 \gt 0$, and I analyzed and wrote up things, in fair detail, on that basis. It certainly should be not too difficult to proofread questions to see whether they accurately represent the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas being used are not quite correct. Note that the problem (at least as first and currently stated) says that the $x_i$ are **bigger** than $0$.

a) Give  $5$ marbles to Kid $1$. We have $13$ marbles left, to be distributed between $4$ kids, at least one to each. By the usual Stars and Bars argument, we need to **choose** $3$ gaps from the $12$ available to put a separator into. There are $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to do this. Another kind of analysis will yield the equivalent answer $\binom{12}{9}$.

You have $\binom{15}{12}$, which is not equal to $\binom{12}{3}$.

(b) You used the right strategy, count all ways, subtract the ways in which $x_4=5$. Let's count these excluded cases. So we need to distribute $13$ marbles between $3$ kids, at least $1$ to each kid. There are $\binom{12}{2}=\binom{12}{10}$ ways to do this. You have something else. The first term is also not right, it should be $\binom{18}{3}$ or $\binom{18}{15}$. The issue here, as usual, is forgetting about the condition $x_i\gt 0$.

c) Now we have $11$ marbles, to be distributed between Kid $1$ and Kid $4$. Hardly need formulas for this. Since each kid has to get at least $1$ marble, there are $10$ ways to do this. You got $12$, which would be the right answer if we allow the possibility of a kid getting no marbles. However, that is ruled out by the beginning of the problem, which says $x_i\gt 0$.

d) There are $4$ ways to distribute $5$ marbles between Kids $1$ and $2$, at least $1$ to each kid. That leaves $13$ marbles to be distributed between Kids $3$ and $4$, at least one to each kid. There are $12$ ways to do this, for a total of $(4)(12)$. You got $(6)(14)$, which would be correct if we allow a kid to have no marbles. But that is excluded.

Comment: Thanks Man , Great Explanation, Thank you.